# Gilt »Du bist schlafend« als Verlaufsform von »Du schläfst«?

Tags: verb, tense

In einer [Antwort zu einer anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/68053/1487) habe ich behauptet, dass es im Deutschen keine Konstruktion gibt, die dem englischen Satz

> You are sleeping.

entspricht. Gemeint war, dass es in der deutschen Standardsprache keine Verlaufsform gibt, die mit der englischen *continuous-* oder *progressive*-Form übereinstimmt.

In Kommentaren wurde

> Du bist am Schlafen.

angeführt, was eindeutig weder Standarddeutsch ist, noch im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum in der Umgangssprache gebräuchlich ist. (Ich lebe im Osten Österreichs, da verwendet niemand diese Konstruktion, laut Wikipedia ist sie nur im Westen des deutschen Sprachraums verbreitet, offenbar mit höchster Frequenz in der Gegend rund um Köln.)

In einem anderen Kommentar wurde aber diese Konstruktion vorgeschlagen:

> Du bist schlafend.

In dieser Konstruktion wird das Verb in ein Partizip I umgewandelt und über eine Form des Kopula *»sein«* prädikativ an das Subjekt gebunden. Das Partizip wird also wie ein prädikatives Adjektiv an das Subjekt gebunden (vergleiche: *»Du bist schön«*)

Ich frage mich nun, ob diese Konstruktion tatsächlich der englischen Verlaufsform entspricht, oder ob sie sich davon prinzipiell unterscheidet.

Comment: Ich denke, "*Du bist schlafend.*" ist ungebräuchlich. Das Partizip I wird eher als Attribut (z.B. "schlafende Hunde") verwendet.

Comment: Aus meiner Sicht beantwortet mein Kommentar nicht die Frage, ob diese Konstruktion der englischen Verlaufsform entspricht. Deshalb würde ich das nicht als Antwort schreiben. Das ist eher ein Hinweis, daß für "*Du bist schlafend*" eine ähnliche Einschränkung gilt wie für "*Du bist am Schlafen.*".

Comment: Die Behauptung, der [am-Progressiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am-Progressiv) sei «eindeutig» nicht Standarddeutsch, ist unhaltbar. Gewiss ist er von Region zu Region unterschiedlich verbreitet, aber trotzdem tritt er durchaus in der Standardsprache auf – die unterscheidet sich bekanntlich ebenfalls von Region zu Region.

Comment: Im Lateinunterricht verwendet man das Partizip in Übersetzungen schon mal so, aber es wirkt immer gestelzt.

Comment: @mach: Standardsprache ist die Sprache, die in Schulen im Deutschunterricht unterrichtet wird, es ist die Sprache in der Schulbücher und Sachbücher gedruckt werden und es ist die Sprache, in der Gesetze, Verordnungen und ähnliche Texte verfasst werden. Ich bin fest überzeugt davon, dass der am-Progressiv weder im Deutschunterricht als korrekte Konstruktion der deutschen Sprache gelehrt wird, noch in einer der genannten Textsorten verwendet wird. Was sich von Region zu Region verändert ist kein staatlicher Standard, sondern die Umgangssprache. ...

Comment: ... Es gibt genau drei Standards der deutschen Sprache, nämlich [deutsches Deutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesdeutsches_Hochdeutsch), [österreichisches Deutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Österreichisches_Deutsch) und [schweizerisches Deutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizer_Hochdeutsch). Italien (Südtirol) verwendet als Amtssprache österreichisches Deutsch, Liechtenstein verwendet schweizerisches Deutsch und Belgien und Luxemburg verwenden als Amtssprache deutsches Deutsch. In der EU sind sowohl deutsches Deutsch als auch österreichisches Deutsch Amtssprachen.

Comment: @mach: Noch eine Ergänzung: Was ich "Umgangssprache" genannt habe, und was du offenbar fälschlicherweise für standardisiertes Deutsch hältst, heißt auch "Alltagssprache". Die Universität Salzburg untersucht schon seit längerem diese nichtstandardisierte Alltagssprache und betreibt eine Website mit dem Titel »Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache«. Die Verlaufsform findet man auf dieser Seite: https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f18a-b/

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Pardon, aber ich verlasse mich lieber auf die Fachliteratur als auf deine Behauptungen. Und laut Fachliteratur ist sich der am-Progressiv in der Standardsprache am Etablieren, vgl. die zahlreichen Quellen in [am-Progressiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am-Progressiv) oder [Verlaufsformen](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f18a-b/). Auch deine Behauptung, was Standard sei, deckt sich nicht mit der Fachliteratur, wo insb. auf die Bedeutung von Pressetexten hingewiesen wird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Konstruktion "Du bist schlafend" ist mir in keinem der deutschen Sprachgebiete, die ich bis jetzt frequentiert habe, je untergekommen, also weder in Südwestdeutschland (Schwaben/Baden) noch im Rheinland noch in den Regionen um Hamburg und Hannover. Sie ist daher, wenn vielleicht nicht falsch, zumindest sehr ungebräuchlich. Die englische Verlaufsform hingegen ist absolut gebräuchlich. Schon von daher entsprechen die beiden Konstruktionen einander nicht.

Darüber hinaus ist die englische Verlaufsform eine eigene Zeitform ("present progressive") mit einer spezifischen, vom "simple present" verschiedenen Bedeutung. Diese Bedeutung hat die Konstruktion "Du bist schlafend" nicht. Sie drückt einfach nur die Zuschreibung der Eigenschaft "schlafend" an das Subjekt des Satzes aus.

Für das englische present progressive gibt es in der Tat im Schriftdeutschen keine Entsprechung, sondern nur Umschreibungen mittels Adverbien wie "gerade". Im rheinischen Dialekt gibt es die in der Frage erwähnte rheinische Verlaufsform: "Du bist am schlafen", gebräuchlich vor allem in der Frageform "Bist du am schlafen?"

Comment: Der Kommentar war von mir. Ich habe auch ausdrücklich erwähnt, dass die Verlaufsform wohl grammatikalisch der Englischen entspricht, allerdings im Deutschen völlig ungebräuchlich ist. Als Österreicher würde ich, wenn schon in einer Art Verlaufsform, sagen: "Du bist beim Schlafen."

Comment: @rexcogitans Alleine die Kombination "Partizip Präsens + <sein>"  *Verlaufsform* zu **nennen** ist nicht richtig. Das Konstrukt ergibt zwar im Deutschen einen richtigen (aber ungebräuchlichen) Satz, der hat aber keinerlei "Verlaufs-Notation"

Answer (score 8):

Ich bin kein deutscher Muttersprachler, aber vielleicht ist die Sichtweise eines englischen Sprechers nützlich. Die Bedeutung von "Du schläfst," ist für mich schon im "*progressive*" Zeitform. Ich würde es nie mit "You sleep," übersetzen, sondern mit "You're sleeping." Im Deutschen gibt es mehrere Interpretationen, aber in der Regel eignet sich die englische "*progressive*" Zeitform am besten. Es ist selten, dass man eine kontinuierliche Bedeutung eindeutig angeben muss. Dies kann jedoch auch ohne die Verwendung von Zeitformen geschehen. Zum Beispiel: "Du schläfst weiter," "Du bleibst im Schlaf."

Comment: Das ist eine wichtige Beobachtung und bekommt deswegen ein +1: "Du schläfst" und "ich arbeite" haben im Deutschen ohne weitere Zusätze "automatisch" schon eine Verlaufs-Notation. (You sleep" and "I work" funktionieren im Englischen nicht.) Man könnte also sagen, eine einfache Subjekt-Verb-Kombination ist im Deutschen schon die Verlaufsform.

Answer (score -2):

Diese Frage habe ich mir auch schon des öfteren gestellt, und die Antwort, zu der ich jedes Mal gelange, ist letztendlich: **Ja, die Formen sind strukturell absolut gleichwertig.**

Über diverse Sprachen lässt sich ein gemeinsames Muster beobachten: Ein Satz der Form

> [Subjekt] [Form von "sein"] [Partizip Präsenz-artige Verbform].

ist grammatikalisch korrekt und drückt aus, was das Subjekt zum beschriebenen Zeitpunkt tut<sup>1</sup>.

Der Unterschied, der freilich für die strukturelle Betrachtung überhaupt keine Rolle spielt, liegt allein in der Gebräuchlichkeit:

- In einigen Sprachen hat sich die Verwendung dieser Konstruktion eingebürgert und sogar dazu geführt, dass sie als eigenständige Zeitform betrachtet wird. So ist im Englisch die Aussage "I am singing." völlig gewöhnlich, ebenso wie das spanische "Estoy cantando."
- In anderen Sprachen hat sich dieselbe Konstruktion überhaupt nicht durchgesetzt. So ist im Deutschen "Ich bin singend." zwar offensichtlich ein grammatikalisch korrekter Satz, jedoch dermaßen unidiomatisch, dass man ihn in einem Schriftstück wohl ohne zu zögern als "falsch" markieren würde.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Die konkrete Interpretation, was dazu zählt und was nicht, hängt häufig von der beschriebenen Aktion und dem Kontext, in dem sie beschrieben wird, ab. Ob man beispielsweise "gerade isst", so lange man die Mahlzeit noch nicht beendet hat, oder nur in genau den Augenblicken, während man einen Bissen im Mund hat, hängt stets davon ab, worauf man mit seiner Aussage gerade hinaus will.

Comment: Die Tatsache, dass die beiden Konstruktionen grammatisch *gleichwertig* sind (was sie tatsächlich sind), heißt noch lange nicht, dass sie auch dasselbe *bedeuten*. Die englische Verlaufsform hinterlegt der Konstruktion die Bedeutung "eben gerade" und "Vorgang" - diese Bedeutung hat die grammatisch gleichwertige deutsche Form überhaupt nicht. (In der Tat hat sie so wenig mehr Bedeutung, als das einfachere "Du schläfst", dass sie keiner benutzt....)

Comment: Ich stimme dir soweit zu, dass die Partizipform sich in beiden Sprachen entspricht. "Schlafend" und "sleeping" sind äquivalente Formen des Verbs. Aber die Kombination dieses Partizips mit "sein" bzw. "to be" *als Verlaufsform des Verbs* gibt es einfach nur im Englischen. Im Deutsche kann man "Sie ist schlafend." theoretisch benutzen, weil man das Partizip "schlafend" auch als Adjektiv interpretieren kann, aber "ist schlafend" ist keine Verlaufsform des Verbs "schlafen".

Comment: Ich kenne keine Sprache außer dem Englischen, in der die Konstruktion "sein + Partizip Präsens" diese spezielle Bedeutung hat. Auch z.B. im Französischen wäre der Satz "Elle est dormante" zwar grammatikalisch korrekt, würde aber nicht als Verlaufsform verstanden.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt: Hättest du meine Antwort gelesen, müsstest du an dem spanischen Beispielsatz vorbeigekommen sein.

Comment: @tofro: 'Die englische Verlaufsform hinterlegt der Konstruktion die Bedeutung "eben gerade" und "Vorgang" - diese Bedeutung hat die grammatisch gleichwertige deutsche Form überhaupt nicht.' - ich verstehe nicht, was dir noch fehlt, damit der Ausdruck die Bedeutung "eben gerade" und "Vorgang" annimmt. Selbstverständlich kann der Satz "Tom ist singend.", so ungebräuchlich er auch sein mag, so verstanden werden, dass Tom *jetzt gerade* den *Vorgang* des Singens durchführt. Es gibt noch weitere Interpretationsmöglichkeiten (die im Englischen prinzipiell auch gegeben sein mögen, aber durch die ...

Comment: ... Verlaufsform als festes Muster vermutlich völlig aus der Wahrnehmung verdrängt sind), aber die Behauptung, dass der Satz auf Deutsch keinen Vorgang ausdrücken *kann*, erscheint mir vollkommen absurd.

Comment: @HalvarF: '"ist schlafend" ist keine Verlaufsform des Verbs "schlafen"' - wie auch tofro möchte ich dich fragen, was genau dir zu einer Verlaufsform fehlt? Eine Bedeutung von "ist schlafend" ist, dass das Subjekt jetzt gerade den Vorgang des Schlafens ausübt. Dass die Konstruktion im Deutschen nicht üblich ist, mag dazu geführt haben, dass wir sie hier nicht mit dem festgesetzten Begriff "Verlaufsform" bezeichnen (denn wozu sollte man auch Bezeichnungen für Konstruktionen vergeben, die überhaupt nicht verwendet werden?). Das schließt ja aber nicht den gedanklichen Sprung aus, dass die ...

Comment: ... besprochene Konstruktion durchaus die "Verlaufsform" *wäre*, würde sie im Sprachgebrauch auftauchen, und somit auch der englischen Verlaufsform im Großen und Ganzen entspricht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich finde dein Argument, dass man keine Bezeichnungen für Formen vergibt, die nicht benutzt werden, hier völlig ausreichend. Im Englischen ist "is ...ing" so gebräuchlich, dass es sinnvollerweise als Form/Tempus des Verbs angesehen wird. Im Deutschen ist die Form "ist ...nd" (also die Kombination des Partizips mit dem Verb "sein") nicht nur wenig gebräuchlich, sondern ungebräuchlich, und es wäre deshalb irreführend, das in der Grammatik der Sprache als eine Form des Verbs zu bezeichnen.